# Exclude element from event handler

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to exclude the image from a click event handler using:

```
$('#templtable .trhover *:not(#infoimg)').live('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');

$('#infoimg').click(function(event) {
          console.log("infoimg");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

And the table looks like this:

```
<table><tr class='trhover'><td><img id='infoimg' src='/images/icon-info.gif' alt='Details'><input type='checkbox' class='followup' id='1' value='234234'></td><td>234234</td></tr><table>
```

However the click event is still active on the image, anu suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: which elements do you want the click event to be registered on?

Comment: On all items in the tr (class=trhover) except for the image item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was not valid. Anyway if You want to exclude the img from executing the click event use selectors `$('tr *:not(img)')`. But it will fire the event while You click the img because when the event is bubbling up. So You must bind an event to stop the propagation.

```
$('.trhover *:not(#infoimg)').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('body').append('click -> '+event.currentTarget.tagName+'<br />');
});
$('#infoimg').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pNaaD/ 
Version with adding rows: http://jsfiddle.net/Zxk8R/

Comment: Does this solution make You happy or did You mean something different?

Comment: Firstly thanks. Your example seems to work just fine. However, on my site it doesn't, although I do exactly the same (see update code above). Could this because the table is dynamically added and thus also the image? 
Furthermore, I noticed that the this in my function became the td instead of the tr due to adding the *:not(#infoimg). Why is that? And how can I keep it on the tr?

Comment: Ok I solved the first part of my question. It is now working. The reasons was that the image is added multiple times with the same id, only the first image will have an event handler... Changed the #infoimg to .infoimg. Do you have any idea on the second part of my question?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zxk8R/. Treat the tr variable as Your desired element. this in our case is each element You click, inside the tr - because we use the *.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I managed to get the tr using $(this).parent();. Everything is working now. Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

Bad bad code...
First, you're not closing your `<tr>`, there's an extra `</td>` instead.
Second, `end()` cancels your filter, which is not properly used anyway, and the `live()` event is deprecated, you should be using `on()`.
If the click is supposed to work on `.trhover` you should do:

```
$('.trhover').on('click', function(){});
```

To stop `<img>` from receiving the `click()` event, you can do what ***czerasz*** suggested.
Also what is the checkbox supposed to do and why did you filter it?